# Pourquoi les serments de Strasbourg?

Tags: histoire

Les [serments de Strasbourg](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/fr/wiki/Serments_de_Strasbourg) sont [souvent](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1439/language-of-franks-vs-later-french/1442#1442) décrits comme la première trace de Français écrit. Le serment de Louis le Germanique est par exemple

> « Pro Deo amur et pro christian poblo et nostro commun salvament, d'ist di in avant, in quant Deus savir et podir me dunat, si salvarai eo cist meon fradre Karlo et in aiudha et in cadhuna cosa, si cum om per dreit son fradra salvar dift, in o quid il mi altresi fazet, et ab Ludher nul plaid nunquam prindrai, qui meon vol cist meon fradre Karle in damno sit. »

La ressemblance avec le Français moderne est assez lointaine. Pourquoi alors faire remonter le Français à ce texte en particulier et ne pas, par exemple, considérer que le Latin aussi est de l'ancien Français ?

Comment: La page wikipedia à laquelle tu renvoies parle quand même d'« une des premières attestations écrites de l'existence d'une langue romane en Francie occidentale (ici l'ancêtre de la Langue d'oïl) et d'un dialecte germanique. » — pas vraiment du français.

Answer (score 6):

Forcément, comparée au français moderne, la langue romane des Serments de Strasbourg ressemble à du latin. Mais si ton point de référence était le latin classique, tu verrais beaucoup de différences. En particulier, on peut déjà constater une nette érosion des cas : il n'y a déjà plus dans le [roman](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_%28langue%29) de l'époque que deux cas, régime et sujet.

Ensuite, ce qui fait qu'une langue est différente d'une autre, c'est l'absence d'intercompréhension. Or c'est justement du IX<sup>e</sup> siècle que date le [concile de Tours](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concile_de_Tours_%28813%29) qui déclare que dans l'empire de Charlemagne, les sermons chrétiens doivent être en « *rusticam Romanam linguam aut Theodiscam* » (langue romane ou tudesque de la campagne). Il s'agit là d'une reconnaissance officielle de ce latin vulgaire comme une langue distincte du latin classique, rélégué aux discussions savantes et religieuses. Les Serments de Strasboug, qui datent d'environ une génération après ce concile sont le plus ancien texte dans cette langue qui nous soit parvenu.

Comment: Si on compare avec le Bas Latin, en revanche, les différences ne sont plus si évidentes. Mais là n'était pas la question. Merci :)

Answer (score 3):

Je pense que le syncrétisme des cas avait effectivement déjà commencé depuis longtemps dans tout l'empire romain, mais la réduction au cas sujet et au cas régime est à mon sens postérieure aux serments de Strasbourg, car « pro christian poblo » a une belle tête d'ablatif, en latin classique ce serait « pro christiano populo », en ancien français quelque chose « por christian peuple ».

Alors je veux bien que lesdits serments soient considérés traditionnellement comme le début du français, mais ça me paraît une approche historique, voire sentimentale, plutôt que scientifique ! La cantilène de sainte Eulalie semble plus justifiée.